# Free data of connections between role and skill

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I'm looking for a FREE dataset of connections beetwen programming(business) skills (e.g. html, python, ios, data structure, unix, api, business development, teamwork) and programming(business) titles (e.g. Business Analyst, Software Architect, Data Engineer, Front End Developer, iOS Developer, Embedded Developer, Engineering Manager).

I'm going to do machine learning on that data and after that machine will know, for example, the connection beetwen the role "iOS Developer" and the skill "css" is very weak, say 10%, or the connection beetwen the role "Front-end developer" and the skill "html" is very strong, say 97%.

So all I need is a data which contains such connections. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say 'free' do you mean 'without cost' or 'not encumbered by usage restrictions'?

Comment: @Joe: Actually, at first I meant them both, but now only the second one will be pretty well.

Answer (score 5):

There are two free data sources that you can use, albeit both are pretty noisy and the job title is a part of a free text field, not an enumerated one.

The first is crossing the user profile page and tagged posts from the Stackoverflow public dump. See [Stackoverflow downloads from the internet archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and 
[Database schema documentation for the public data dump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

The second is scrapping the LinkedIn public API for profile properties. These include both job descriptions and skills. Contrary to the first, you may have to wait for a while, because of usage limitations.